# Laravel validation - Different Attributes Specifications

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm using a LaravelMiddleware, which should check for Access.
Therefore, I check for a specific Attributes, which sometimes have different names.

> EG:
>
> 1. $request->key
> 2. $request->moduleKey

Im asking if there is a possiblitiy to check for 2 different attributes specifications?

Like so:

```
$data = $request->validate([
   'key|moduleKey' => ['required', 'numeric'],   
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible this way, but you have 2 other options:

#### Validation

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-without

```php
$data = $request->validate([
   'key' => ['required_without:moduleKey', 'numeric'],   
   'moduleKey' => ['required_without:key', 'numeric'],   
]);
```

but the problem is you still dont know which one you need unless you always get them both: `$data['key'] ?? $data['moduleKey']`

You can also update the request beforenhand:

```php
$request['key'] = $request['key'] ?? $request['moduleKey'];
$data = $request->validate([rules]);
```

this code above you could put in a middleware to make sure every request always have the "key" variable in the request.